# jQuery copy selectbox selected value to another selectbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Is it possible to copy a selected option from the first dropdown to another using Jquery and disallowing the user from copying the SAME option ?

[image]

Comment: if is this a question "Is it possible to copy a selected option from the first dropdown to another using Jquery ?" then yes you can by using jquery. Come with a code we will help you.

Comment: I ment using Jquery ... I just have no idea where to begin since it's my first time playing with it

Comment: did you searched? if yes you may find various tutorial on this. one of which is - http://voidcanvas.com/move-option-from-one-select-box-to-another-and-vice-versa/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HTML Markup

```
<select id="one" multiple="multiple">
    <option>one</option>
    <option>two</option>
    <option>three</option>
</select>

<select id="two" multiple="multiple">

</select>
```

Jquery

```
$('#one option').click(function() {
   $(this).clone().appendTo("#two");
});
```

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/Animeshjain/3JqhG/)**

Comment: Oh you're my hero ! Is it also possible to remove them from the first list and transfer them to second

Comment: yeah that is possible. Just remove the .clone() method.

Comment: Already it works from one way around ! Thanks ! I removed the button and did it your way. Now I tried it the way around from the second list to the first ( so the user can but it back in the first list if he made a mistake ) but it's copies itself for some strange reason lol

Comment: To achieve that you need to use a jQuery plugin. See the demo at http://www.voidcanvas.com/demo/7511pair-select/ and the tutorial at http://voidcanvas.com/move-option-from-one-select-box-to-another-and-vice-versa/ . Accept the answer if your question is being answered.

Answer (score 1):

Yes:

```
var option = $("#idOfSelect option:eq(0)"); //eq 0 targets the first option, change to what you need
$("#idOfOtherSelect").append(option);
```

Answer (score 0):

Like this:

```
$('#first').change(function(){

    $('#second').append("<option value="+$(this).val()+">"+$("#first option:selected").text()+"</option>")

})
```

[**FIDDLE EXAMPLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/LAeY7/4/)

Answer (score 0):

Example:

```
$("#copy").on("click", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $("#select1 option:selected").clone().appendTo($("#select2"));
});
```